# Rewriting Web.config rule applying to all requests

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, friendly-url

I spent a few hours trying to find a way (I do not really grasp the tangled IIS docs) to make URLS friendly while keeping a single entry point within the public folder. I mean, when the user types:

```
"localchosy/myproject/route1"
```

Internally the rule redirects it to:

```
"localhost/myproject/public/index.php/route1"
```

The rule I wrote is and that (i thought) work like a charm, is:

```
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <!-- REWRITING INDEX.PHP -->
                <rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true" >
                    <match url="[/^myproject$/]{1}(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="myrpoject/public/index.php" />    
                </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Despite the fact that I still need to add https enforcement and block direct access to folders, it did the work (the app is still beta). But, to my surprise, when I wrote

```
localhost/phpmyadmin
```

The server redirected rewrited it as

```
localhost/myproject/public/index.php/phpmyadmin
```

The irs clearly something I don't understand about those rules. I thought that the "match" tag meant that the rule applied only if there was a regex match, but it clearly isn't the case... In fact, the prefix I am using withing the url attribute inside the match tag is doing nothing... I don't understand.

How can I make the rule to only apply to URLS starting with "myproject"...

PS: CUrrently I have the web.config file inside inetub/wwwroot, at the same elevel of the projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your rule and did some changes. Please try this.

```
<rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="myproject/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="myrpoject/public/index.php/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="myproject/public/(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>    
</rule>
```

This is the log of Failed Request Tracing.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That triggers a "no file input specified" error. I'm using php with cgi, if that helps....

Comment: Sorry. It works perfectly (I had a typo). Thank you very much, you saved me